# Download attribute not working in Phonegap app

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

This is not my first hybrid app (I've published apps on both Google Play Store and Apple Store). My target platform is Android. I'm not sure which versions will be supported, I will determine that later if I decide to publish this idea at all.. I'm using Phonegap Build.

I'm having some trouble getting the HTML Download attribute of the A element to work. Here's what I have:

```
<a download href="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg">Lamb</a>
```

If I remove the download attribute, the image opens in my phonegap app (Android). With it, nothing happens though. Works fine in at least Chrome, too. Any ideas?

Comment: there is not enough information in your post to offer any sort of solutions. Please **answer the following questions in your post**.
Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question, respond in the comments so I know you have added the  information.

Comment: Hi Jesse, Thanks for your response. No, this is not my first hybrid app (I've published apps on both Google Play Store and Apple Store). Target platform is Android. Honestly I'm not sure which versions will be supported, I will determine that later if I decide to publish this idea at all.. I'm using Phonegap Build.

Comment: phonegap webview can't download files, you should use the file-transfer plugin

Comment: @Robbert The reason I ask people to put information in the **post** is so other can learn from the questions. As happens jcesarmobile has the correct answer, but no details. I'll post details as an answer in just a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Robbert,
I answer alot of *Cordova/Phonegap* questions like alot of volunteers on this forum. As such, you might find this FAQ useful.

- [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

From this FAQ, you want to be aware of #5 - Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005). This is common mistake. It is true you can use your webbrowser to test you pages, but don't be fooled into thinking that all webbrowsers are the same. As Paul Irish likes to remind use "Not all webbrowser are equal". His article [Webkit for Developers](http://www.paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/) is a good read.

**I quote**

> Different ports can have different focuses. The Mac port’s focus is split between Browser and OS, and introduces Obj-C and C++ bindings to embed the renderer into native applications. Chromium’s focus is purely on the browser. QtWebKit offers its port for applications to use as a runtime or rendering engine within its cross-platform GUI application architecture.

To be clear, Phonegap uses a library called [webview](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview.md) (with Android, and similar on other platforms). The current incarnation is based on Chromium's "webkit", but previously it was based on an old version of Android "webview" - which was around for years. However, even with *the attribute you are looking for may not be available.*

The best was place to start is [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/). A search for [download](http://caniuse.com/#search=download) shows that `download` is mostly supported, but missing is IE, Safari, and Opera. Otherwise, it appears it is available, but only for Android after 4.4. Looking at my [notes](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview.md) this appears to coincide with Android starting to use Chromium's webkit, and not the dated webview library — as i stated before.

**Possible Solutions**

As @jcesarmobile alluded to you can use

- [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

**_OR_**

You can try another webview library that might have the attribute you are looking for 
- like [crosswalk](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/).

At this time, [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) only supports Android, but there are also a few beta version you can also try that are in [the repository](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=crosswalk). And, if your target platform is iOS, then use [WKWebview](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=wkwebview) instead.

**NOTE** the standard webview library is already on your mobile device, crosswalk is separate and will add at least 20megabytes to your app.

Comment: Thank you. You asked a good question - which is rare. A good question means other developers will learn from this - which is my ultimate goal. FWIW: I'm working on robotics with Javascript - which includes node.js. I think in a few years JS will be the choice for most robotic developers.

Comment: Is this also the case for files that are stored within the app? Files that don't need server side interaction. So instead of http://.... as path it is stored locally like path/file.mp3. Because it is also not working with local files.

Comment: Local files that are stored within the same "app bundle" can, of course, be read. There are a few caveats.  #1 certain media types require exact path description, as is required by the underlying Operating System. For example, Android requires the [media plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/) path to be /android_assests/www/(path)/media.mp3. If you are looking for an example app, here is an example app I wrote [phonegap-media-test](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Media-Test)