# Why is my download button in phonegap app not working?

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have made a working download button with html that is referring to a sound in de websites folder. When I convert this with phonegap it is not working annymore.

Html code:

```
<a href="path to local sound" target="_blank" download>Download this sound</a>
```

The sounds can be played withing the app generated with phonegap, so that means that the path and sound are matched correctly.

Comment: You should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960412/download-attribute-not-working-in-phonegap-app?rq=1